# How to use Laravel Eloquent to fetch from two tables (Albums & Tracks)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have two tables, albums and tracks and in my albums table i have this
albums = 'id', 'title','artist_id', 'genre_id', 'track_id'
 While in my tracks table i have this
tracks = 'id', 'title', 'album_id', 'artist_id'

in my Album.php Model i have

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Album extends Model
{
    public function artist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Artist');
    }

    public function genre()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Genre');
    }

    public function track()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Track');
    }
}
```

and in my Track.php Model i have

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Track extends Model
{
    public function artist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Artist');
    }
    public function albums()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');
    }
}
```

In My Track Controller I have

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Track;
use App\Http\Resources\Track as TrackResource;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrackController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Get tracks
        $tracks = Track::with('albums')->get();

        // Return collection of albums as a resource
        return TrackResource::collection($tracks);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $track = new Track();

        $track->title = $request->input('title');
        $track->album_id = $request->input('album_id');
        $track->artist_id = $request->input('artist_id');
        $track->duration = $request->input('duration');
        $track->release_date = $request->input('release_date');
        $track->track_position = $request->input('track_position');
        $track->track_link = $request->input('track_link');

        if($track->save()) {
            return new TrackResource($track);
        }else{
            return "Error Saving";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        // Get single track
        $track = Track::findOrFail($id);

        // Return single track as a resource
        return new TrackResource($track);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // Get single track
        $track = Track::findOrFail($id);

        if($track->delete()) {
            return "deleted";
        }else{
            return "Error Deleting";
        }
    }
}
```

Album Controller I have

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Album;
use App\Http\Resources\Album as AlbumResource;

class AlbumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Get albums
        $albums = Album::with('artist')->orderBy('artist_id', 'desc')->limit(8)->get();

        // Return collection of albums as a resource
        return AlbumResource::collection($albums);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $album = new Album();

        $album->title = $request->input('title');
        $album->artist_id = $request->input('artist_id');
        $album->genre_id = $request->input('genre_id');
        $album->artwork_path = $request->input('artwork_path');
        $album->album_date = $request->input('album_date');
        $album->upc = $request->input('upc');
        $album->record_label = $request->input('record_label');

        if($album->save()) {
            return new AlbumResource($album);
        }else{
            return "Error Saving";
        }
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        // Get single album
        $album = Album::findOrFail($id);

        // Return single album as a resource
        return new AlbumResource($album);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // Get single album
        $album = Album::findOrFail($id);

        if($album->delete()) {
            return "deleted";
        }else{
            return "Error Deleting";
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to display all the (tracks) related to an (album) under that album.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using relationships: [Laravel eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Just add this function to the Album model:

```
public function tracks () {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Track');
}
```

And this to your Track model:

```
public function album () {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');
}
```

That way you can get the tracks of a single album like this:

```
$tracks = App\Album::find($id)->tracks();
```

Comment: i am having this error: ErrorException: Trying to get property &#039;id&#039; of non-object in file C:\xampp\htdocs\api\app\Http\Resources\Album.php on line 40 and also here is my Resource code 'trackDetails' => [
                'id' => $this->track->id,
                'trackName' => $this->track->title,
                'trackDuration' => $this->track->duration,
                'trackLink' => $this->track->track_link,
                'trackArtist' => $this->artist->name,
                'trackPosition' => $this->track->track_position,
            ],

Comment: Well, by looking at that you may need to configure the argument of the hasMany/belongsTo. I assumed your models where in "App\Album" but it seems like your Album model is in "App\Http\Resources\Album".

Comment: how can i get all tracks of an album with id of 1?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 


class Album extends Entity
{
    protected $table = 'albums';

    public function tracks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Track::class);
    }
}


class Track extends Entity
{
    protected $table = 'tracks';

    public function album()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Album::class);
    }

    public function artist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Artist::class);
    }
}

class Artist extends Entity
{
    protected $table = 'artists';

    public function tracks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Track::class);
    }
}

//  Get all traks of album : 
$tracks = Album::find($id)->tracks();

// or all albums and their respective tracks : 
$albums = Album::with('tracks')->get();


//  Get all traks of artist : 
$tracks = Artist::find($id)->tracks();

// or all artists and their respective tracks : 
$artists = Artist::with('tracks')->get();
```

Know more about relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: i am getting this error: Exception: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php on line 2011
Stack trace:

Comment: Can you show your code where you are getting this please?

Comment: how can i get all tracks of an album with id of 1?

Comment: Album::find($id)->tracks;

Comment: ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$id in file C:\xampp\htdocs\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\DelegatesToResource.php on line 120

Comment: ohh my bad you need () after `tracks()`

Comment: When you do $tracks = `Album::find($id)->tracks();` It will give you all tracks. You need to foreach to get id of each track.

Comment: it is still not working, i have uploaded it to github and i would love if you could help me check it. I am working on an API

Comment: Sure can you send me the link?

Comment: here is the link: https://github.com/henrymainmonstajams2018/larastream/invitations. I would love to display all the tracks on each album and also display all the tracks and albums on each playlist

Comment: See my recent pull request https://github.com/henrymainmonstajams2018/larastream/pull/1

Comment: Yes check the PR url I sent above

Comment: it did not work, it still gave me an error.. Did you ran it and it worked over there? How can i chat with you personally apart from here?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your keys in your relationship's function if you do not defined in your DB. Try to put another related key in relationship's function like this

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

For more information [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

Hope it wiil be helpful to you :)